# If a function is bounded and continuous does it imply it is Lipshitz function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let f be a real valued function. If f is bounded and continuous on an Interval does it imply it is Lipshitz function on that interval? Also does there exist an unbounded function on (0,1) which is Lipshitz function?

I couldn'nt think of any counter example and intuitively it feels true to me but I was not able to prove it.

Comment: No and No. Please show your attempt.

Comment: (1) $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is continuous and bounded on $[0,1]$. But it is not Lipshitz: given any $M>0$, select $a,b\in (0,\frac{1}{4M^2})$. Then $|\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}>\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2M}+\frac{1}{2M}}=M$. Therefore $f$ is not Lipshitz on $[0,1]$. (2) $f$ is Lipshitz on $(0,1)$ $\implies$ $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$ $\implies$ $f$ can be continuously extended to $[0,1]$ (well-known fact). Therefore the extension of $f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$, and a fortiori bounded on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ on $(0,1)$, it is bounded and continuous on $(0,1)$ But it is not Lipschitz...

Suppose it is Lipschitz,

then there $\exists$ $L$, such that $\forall x,y \in (0,1)$ $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}| \leq L|x-y|$,

Let $x=0$, then $\sqrt{y} \leq L y,$

$\implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\leq L, \forall y  \in (0,1)$

But, given $L \in \mathbb{R}, \exists n: n>L$,

Now choose $y=\frac{1}{n^2}$
, Then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\leq L \implies n \leq L$

but that's a contradiction , because we choose $n$, such that $n>L.$

Hence $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is not Lipschitz on $(0,1)$, but it is bounded and continuous on $(0,1) $

For the second question refer "https://math.stackexchange.com/a/790975/1077989"